# SSH 'Authenticity of host' warning after numerous previous connections

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

I have a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04 and I've connected to it via SSH from my current machine numerous times.  I just tried to connect and was given this error:

```
The authenticity of host '142.---------' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:----------------------------.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

I was able to confirm the fingerprint by logging in through the DigitalOcean console and running this command:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

I also then connected to a different droplet and didn't get the warning.

Is there a way for me to identify why I got that warning?

Comment: On the client machine look in file `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and see if the entry for this host is correct, damaged in any way, commented out, or missing altogether. If you have more than one user/account on the client machine (which isn't common nowadays) check each one. Also, could the host's IPaddress have changed?

Comment: There is an entry in the known_hosts file.  How can I tell if it's damaged?  Also, the IP address hasn't changed.

Comment: Actually I just realized; if you 'confirmed' the fingerprint and proceeded with the connection, that updated the `known_hosts` file -- check the mod time -- so we probably can't see what was in it _when the problem happened_ unless you have a backup. If you have the file contents from that time and they contain a line in the format described in [the man page for sshd](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8#SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE_FORMAT) (for 7.4 up, before that the man page was out of date) and matching that host, you should not have gotten the warning message.

Comment: I was going to connect just to check something and I ended up checking it through the Digital Ocean console.  So I never connected with SSH and it was still showing the IP in the known_hosts file.